# automatic generate invoice worksheet name excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, invoice, vba

I have a workbook where the worksheet name has to be edited every time when open a new invoice.

Is it possible for it to generate invoice number automatically in an incremental manner? By using VBA or macros?

How and where should i start?

Comment: Pplease add more information. How do you open the invoice? Do you really need to change the worksheet name? etc.

Comment: usually i will just right click at my master copy, and tick the create a copy box and move to end

Comment: after that i will change the created sheet name to something like P00001

Answer (score 0):

P, this should give you a starting point for a macro you can invoke with a key sequence, or place a form button on you mastersheet to activate. This copies the current worksheet (mastersheet) to the end and renames it to "P"+ whatever you choose for an invoice number. Then increments the invoice number by 1 for the next invoice and puts that value in K1 on the mastersheet. Of course, edit as needed. Hope this helps if you haven't found a solution yet.

```
Sub CopySheet_End()
Dim InvNum
  '__pick a cell to put an invoice number in, like K1__
InvNum = ActiveSheet.Range("K1").Value

ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "P" & InvNum

InvNum = InvNum + 1
Sheets("MasterSheet").Select
Range("K1").Value = InvNum

End Sub
```

Comment: will try out your solution and modify it, thanks a lot mamalmgren